# how to make dom manipulation more clear

Tags: javascript, dom

Have some code like:

```
var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');

var c = this.chart;

el.setAttribute('x', c.x + c.padding + 'px');
el.setAttribute('y', c.y + c.padding + i * (b.height + b.margin) + 'px');
el.setAttribute('width', model.value * c.scale + 'px');
el.setAttribute('height', b.height + 'px');
el.classList.add('bar');

this.svg.appendChild(el);
```

Any options to make it look not as ugly? There is a chance that can be more attributes...

Comment: What's so ugly about it?

Comment: You may name it as a perfectionist call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time to use a function? Something like:

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
```

And call it as:

```
setAttributes(elem, {"src": "http://example.com/something.jpeg", "height": "100%", ...});
```

Comment: the same thoughts, but some of values should be calculated that makes `attrs` a bit messy

Comment: Then you can have a general function as above (which will be helpful at many places in future) and for special cases you can first calculate the values and then call the function passing values in attrs.